# have button input and need to make it download known url

Tags: jquery

I have  tag and I have a custom url gotten by jquery , all I want to make a button click and download that custom url by jquery ?

```
<button>
download mp3 file
</button>
```

I know I can do it with Link tag but I need button tag to do it

Comment: There is alot left out here. Are you required to do it over the form, is it a static url or dynamic? Is this a school homework ;)? Do you want to use a library or write it from scratch? Do you want to use javascript or a framework like jquery or just pure html?
This question has been answered many times before here and one of those answers might or might not fit your needs. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33664398/how-to-download-file-using-javascript-only

Comment: thanks a lot, I get it by making it :
~
  $(location).attr('href',$href);
~
$href = my custom link download 
So when click on button it redirect to that link and download